# Intellij - how to discover called functions?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to understand a complicated legacy java app. My goal is to know what services/utilities are triggered by a specific HTTP request.

Is there any tool available in Intellyj to collect function calls within a specified timeframe?

Comment: You could try using Endpoints view https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/endpoints-tool-window.html